# Is ANN a data structure or an algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks

When I read about Artificial Neural Networks (ANN), no one says what ANN is.

For instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) says:

> Artificial neural networks (ANNs), usually simply called neural networks (NNs), are **computing systems** vaguely inspired by the biological neural networks that constitute animal brains.

This is a vague definition. This definition begs question "What does it mean by a ***Computing System***?"

[IBM's definition](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/neural-networks) is as follows:

> Neural networks, also known as artificial neural networks (ANNs) or simulated neural networks (SNNs), are a subset of machine learning and are at the heart of deep learning algorithms. Their name and structure are inspired by the human brain, mimicking the way that biological neurons signal to one another.

This is also an unclear and vague definition. This is also a recursive definition that depends on the definition of machine learning.

So, my question is,

1. What is an ANN?
2. Is ANN a data structure or an algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "artificial neural network" is usually just referred to as "neural network" (NN) in the literature.

The term NN is used to describe a set of functions, that can be described by a parameter. Think of it like you would think of the function $f_a(x)=ax$, it is a function that has a parameter $a$, and differs by different choices of $a$. For example, if $a=1$ then $f_a(x)=x$ and if $a=5$ then $f_a(x)=5x$. In the same sense, a neural network is a function with a vector-type parameter, usually denoted by $\theta$.

Hence, a NN is a function.

If you would like to know more about what exactly neural networks are, how they compute things, and how they can "learn" (and also see some real code demonstrating those abilities), then I can recommend you to read [this (mini) book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html).

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer twice.  What a great explanation!

Comment: Thanks! glad to hear that :)